# smarty with DOMPDF issue the result is not imported into pdf file?

Tags: php, smarty, dompdf

iam in the middle of development. i have to create a PDF file from the result. please review my code, the PDF is created but its in empty.

**Code:**

```
case 'pre-test-pdf': 
    ob_start();
    require_once("includes/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");     
    $smarty->display('default/content/pdf/pdf-view-pre-test.tpl');      
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
 break;
```

The Result of this page has to be a PDF

```
$smarty->display('default/content/pdf/pdf-view-pre-test.tpl');
```

Expecting a solution soon.

Comment: first print the html using echo, if you get as u want then create pdf

Comment: how can i get the tpl file result into pdf

Comment: thats why pdf is empty... first get that html code layout

Comment: yes i know the issue. but i dont know how to get a html layout. you have any idea to create a PDF through smarty tpl file.

Comment: sorry, i dont know smarty, i was created pdf with html code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21305/discussion-between-daya-and-raj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write $html = $smarty->fetch('default/content/pdf/pdf-view-pre-test.tpl'); This will give the html layout of your file which is stored in $html and that can be used to create PDF.